# Проблемы с кодировкой в Apache Tika wrapper для PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, файлы, apache

Есть задача - вытащить текст из файла и положить в бд для индексации. Для вытаскивания текста использую обертку на PHP для Apache Tika (https://github.com/NinoSkopac/PhpTikaWrapper).
Если вызывать метод из веба:

```
$text = TikaWrapper::getText('test.docx');
var_dump($text);
```

То все русские символы в файле отображаются как "?", при этом английский текст отображается нормально.
Запуская тот же самый скрипт из консоли - все русские символы отображаются нормально.
В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить? Крайне необходимо использовать библиотеку из веба.

Comment: Не пробовали преобразовать полученную строку `$text` в `utf-8`? Или `getText` возвращает не строку?

Comment: @DmitriySaxarov пробовал iconv, mb_convert_encoding и даже setlocale. Но я уже нашел способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению не сразу, но нашел решение.
Я пытался ставить локаль на utf-8 с помощью setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8'), но это не давало эффекта.
Помогло использование putenv('LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8'), честно говоря я не понял какая разница между setlocale и putenv, но это помогло мне.